# Variable inside window.opener is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I have a very simple page from which I'm showing some thumbnails, and i want to click on them to show the enlarged image.

So I'm setting a click function in the main page for the object class ".pic":

```
$(".pic").click( function() {
    var img_data = {};
    img_data.img_name= $(this).attr("src");
    img_data.img_caption= $(this).attr("alt");
    var img_win=window.open("apri_foto.html","_blank","height=600"); 
});
```

and this is the code into the child window

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data=window.opener.img_data;
    alert (data);
});
```

the problem now is that in the child window the variable is undefined.
I have also tried to due the inverse, i.e. setting from the parent directory, but it is not working. I now it is very easy but I really don't understand where I am wrong. To anticipate the doubt, the page opened is from the same domain (it is in the same folder).
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the scope of the `img_data` variable: it's local. You need to put that in the global scope, otherwise it will be destroyed when the click handler exits. That means you need to define it outside any function:

```
var img_data = {};

$(".pic").click( function() {
    img_data.img_name= $(this).attr("src");
    img_data.img_caption= $(this).attr("alt");
    var img_win=window.open("apri_foto.html","_blank","height=600"); 
});
```

[More about scope](https://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/)